# How to cover the whole screen by transparent view (alpha 80%), except for some elements?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, transparent, android-tablayout

I have a button by click on which all screen should became darker, except for this button. I tried to change color, theme,but it doesn't give me what I exactly want. Now I have an idea to cover the whole screen by half-transparent view and it works, but covers only area under *ToolBar*. The problem is that I can't figure out how fix it. I can't cover *ToolBar* and can't figure our how to leave my button visible. 
It should be like this:
[image: screenshot]

I'm sure there's a simple way to do it, if somebody worked with it, please explain.

I'm trying to do it like this: in activity_main.xml I added *View* and by button click I make it visible. But it again covers only area under Tab header.

```
  <View
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="20"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </View>
```

Full layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="20"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </View>

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Your Wi-Fi is online">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="36dp"
      android:layout_margin="17dp"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:text="@string/pause"
      android:textColor="@color/midPurple"
      android:textSize="14sp" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change the background color

Comment: @Anonymous It doesn't work for ToolBar, I only cover this area under Tab header

Comment: Are you using a custom ToolBar? And please provide the full xml file.

Comment: @H.Brooks No, it's from support library.

Comment: Ok please provide the full xml layout

Comment: @H.Brooks Button which I need to be visible is in ToolBar

Comment: You want to shade the main content and the toolbar except for one toolbar button, is that it?

Comment: @nandsito Yes, but probably soon this dark area will should be available to user. But for now I want at least make it looks like on the screenshot I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first thing I thought of, there could be easier ways , but this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/darkOverLay_Content"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="20"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </View>

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Your Wi-Fi is online">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="36dp"
      android:layout_margin="17dp"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:text="@string/pause"
      android:textColor="@color/midPurple"
      android:textSize="14sp" />


    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#80000000"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:id="@+id/darkOverLay_ToolBar"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your java class you can do the following:

```
ImageView darkOverLay_Content = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.darkOverLay_Content);
ImageView darkOverLay_ToolBar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id. darkOverLay_ToolBar);
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. btn_pause);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ***Do what you want with the click here***
        if(darkOverLay_Content.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {

            darkOverLay_Content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            darkOverLay_ToolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

            darkOverLay_Content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            darkOverLay_ToolBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
}});
```

In this answer I'm using 2 `ImageView`s,  with 80% transparency, one for the toolBar and one for the content, then I set the visibility of this `ImageView`s. This can be changed accordingly.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: It again works only for everything under Tab header. But it covers Toolbar text :) Which API level have you tried ?

Comment: What do you mean with "But it covers Toolbar text"? Do you want the text in the ToolBar to be fully visible at all times?

Comment: Yes, like on the screen. I don't know why, but it fully covers it. And I though it maybe cuz of API level, I have 26

Comment: It has nothing to do with the API you are using. In the example you have given the Text in the ToolBar looks to me to darker, and not fully visible. To have complete control over your ToolBar I would advise you to create/use a custom ToolBar.

Comment: yeah, i tried a few things and it seems that we have little control over the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

For the view that covers whole screen you may set a transparent background. For Whatever views are above that
You may set transparent background if you want them to be transparent.